# How to display multiple image view in android studio

Tags: android-studio, imageview, android-camera

I want to display multiple image view which the images are taken from camera. However, I only know how to display 1. Anyone know how to display multiple image view? Thanks for help!

```
public class ItemRegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_register);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
}
```

Actually I have a solution like this

```
public class ItemRegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView1,imageView2,imageView3,imageView4;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_register);
    this.imageView1 = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
        }
    });
    this.imageView2 = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);
        }
    });
    this.imageView3 = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 3);
        }
    });
    this.imageView4 = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imageView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 4);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView2.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
    if (requestCode == 3 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView3.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
    if (requestCode == 4 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView4.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
}
```

Is there any other way to do this? Must use recycle view? Thanks!

Comment: Use a recyclerview

Comment: Would you mind give me some example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am not able to comment because of less reputation. But [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747018/recyclerview-display-multiple-images) you can see how to implement RecyclerView with multiple Image View. I hope it would be helpful to you.

Comment: I have added my other solution to the question. However, that solution look quite stupid. So, is the recycle view a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: If you are dealing with large data set then Recycler view is better then your solution but if you are having only four images then no need to implement Recycler View.

Comment: Ok thanks, other than recycle view, is there any other solution for large data set?